# SSHException('No existing session') при запуске 500 multiprocessing процессов создающих ssh-соединения с помощью paramiko

Tags: python, multiprocessing, paramiko

Пытаюсь создать скрипт для конфигурации хостов по ssh через paramiko с помощью модуля multiprocessing. Тк узлов порядка 500, то обработка их по очереди занимает очень много времени. Есть следующий код:

```
import time
import sys
import paramiko
import socket
import re
import multiprocessing
host = open('/home/user/hosts', 'r')
hosts = host.readlines()
host.close()
def connect_ssh(host, queue):
        try:
            remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()

            remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
            paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

            remote_conn_pre.connect(host, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False, timeout=5)
            time.sleep(0.2)

            print("SSH connection established to %s" % host)
            remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
            print("Interactive SSH session established")

            ###здесь операции с хостами####

               queue.put({host: output})

        except (socket.gaierror,socket.timeout,TimeoutError):
                print("Could not connect to %s \n" % host)
                sys.exit(1) 


def send_commands(function):
    processes = []
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for l in range(len(hosts)):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target = function, args = (hosts[l], queue))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p) 
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    results = []
    for p in processes:
        results.append(queue.get())
    return results

send_commands(connect_ssh)
```

Если применять его к небольшой группе узлов (порядка 10 например) то все работает корректно. Но стоит только запустить выполнение на все 500 устройств, то на половине (причем рандомно) вываливается такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "scripts/qos_add_mp.py", line 24, in connect_ssh
    remote_conn_pre.connect(host, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False, timeout=5)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 341, in connect
    server_key = t.get_remote_server_key()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 670, in get_remote_server_key
    raise SSHException('No existing session')
```

При этом, насколько я понял, ошибка характерна для случаев когда в connect paramiko не указывают ключи look_for_keys=False и allow_agent=False. Но они у меня есть. В чем может быть загвоздка?

Comment: 1- можно потоки вместо процессов для ввода/вывода использовать 2- попробуйте пул потоков (к примеру ~40) вместо запуска сразу всех 500 процессов. [Пример кода](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31795242/4279)

Comment: Если вы действительно хотите сразу к  500 хостам обращаться, то попробуйте gevent + paramiko или asyncssh, чтобы 500 потоков не создавать. Или вообще [используйте fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) (который за вас multiprocessing + paramiko под капотом использует).

Comment: Как ответ не понятнет, но как идея - подойдет. Если у Вас уже есть 500 машин, то может некоторые из них использовать как "суперузлы" - то есть основной скрипт раздает им задания, а они уже разбрасывают их по своим "дочерним узлам". После выполнения, информация пробрасывается назад к главному управяющему узлу. Думаю, конфигурация 25х20 сработает хорошо. Сами суперузлы можно вторым заходом обновить. Способ будет хорошо масштабироваться. При кол-ве узлов больше 1000 видимо придется вводить ещё один промежуточный этап.

Comment: Я думаю, вы упираетесь в типичное ограничение 1024 файловых дескриптора на процесс. А решение вам только что подсказали, делать новый обслуживающий *процесс* для группы допустимого размера (или обрабатывать "пачками" в пуле).

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Насчет суперузлов, это не вариант, тк под хостами я подразумеваю маршрутизаторы, работающие в мплс сети. Решение первоначальной ошибки было найдено уменьшением количества процессов, до 65. В итоге за примерно 8-9 итераций скрипт справлялся. Что дало сокращение времени работы скрипта вместо 8 часов, до 35 минут.

Comment: ещё как вариант: [`parallel-ssh`](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh). Или как есть использовать или посмотреть реализацию (gevent + paramiko: на предмет того, что работает/не работает в вашем случае --  c `pool_size` поиграйтесь).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему 500 процессов это слишком много. Сделайте хотя бы так:

```
NUM_PROCESS = 10
queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
results = []

while hosts:
    processes = []
    for _ in range(NUM_PROCESS):
        if not hosts:
            break
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(hosts.pop(), queue))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
        results.append(queue.get())
return results
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробую данный вариант. 

Я пришел к такому же выводу, но решил немного иначе, функцию send_commands полностью переделал с использованием Pool:

`def send_commands(function):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=50)
    p.map(connect_ssh, hosts, 1)
    p.close()
    p.join()`

Comment: Ну можно и так) Наверное даже лучше(не надо заморачиваться с управлением)

Comment: Осталась последняя (я надеюсь) проблема) Оба варианта, описанных выше, работают. Но у обоих вариантов финал выполнения скрипта одинаков - он просто виснет и почти все процессы, вместо того, чтобы завершиться - просто остаются как зомби. Пробовал try/finally, но эффект тот же.

Comment: 1. уберите sys.exit(), порождение того же ислючения будет достаточно 2. Строку созадния замените на p = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(hosts.pop(), queue), deamon=True)

Comment: К сожалению этот вариант так же висит( Но зато удалось обойти это залипание процессов таким образом, вместо блока

`for p in processes:
        p.join()
        results.append(queue.get())`

изменяем на этот:

`while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            if not multiprocessing.active_children():
                break
            results.append(queue.get())`

Comment: Да что за издевательтелство опять... За что минус то влеплен? Я что блин должен Вангой стать или что? 2 раз уже такое происходит..

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите конфигурировать 500 хостов по ssh, изучите очень крутой инструмент - [ansible](https://www.ansible.com)

Для него уже сделано очень много рецептов, да и в жизни знание такого инструмента пригодится больше, чем изобретение велосипеда

Comment: Я знаком с ансибл, но в данном случае задача была в использовании python multiprocessing ))

Answer (score -1):

Думаю проблема в timeout=5. и происходит както так:

1) новый connect_ssh-процесс посылает какието данные в ssh и "ждет" ответ

тк одновременно работает только один процесс, см GIL:

2) во время "ожидания" multiprocessing переключается на другой connect_ssh-процесс, те переход в пункт 1)

Так происходит по кругу, == кол-во ваших процессов

3) Допустим во время этой multiprocessing connect-карусели, в первый connect_ssh-процесс пришел ответ от ssh-компа, но тк число процессов 500, multiprocessing не успевает переключится обратно(за отведенные 5 сек), чтобы обработать ответ

```
import multiprocessing

hosts = 'h1', 'h2', 'h3'

def connect_ssh(host):
    # ...
    return host

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        results = pool.map(connect_ssh, hosts)
    print(results)
```

Comment: 1- Каждый Питон процесс имеет свой GIL (это значит, что сколько процессов одновременно работает зависит от OS, железа, но не от Питона) 2- даже если бы потоки бы использовались, а не процессы, даже в этом случае, Питон отпускает GIL во время IO операций. GIL не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме в вопросе.

Comment: Изначально timeout=5 не стояло. Поставил, тк было слишком большое время ожидания, когда хост недоступен. С active_children скрипт пару раз тоже подвисал, поэтому причина такого поведения до конца не ясна. Учитывая что другие варианты решения у людей работали корректно...